# Plotly: single legend for multiple aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, legend-properties, r-plotly

Is there any way to use a single legend for multiple aesthetics in Plotly? I use ggplot to plot several weeks of data and it gets very noisy. Therefore, I use both color and shape to differentiate them and ggplot just combines them in the legend. Here is a reproducible example:

```
p<- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,wt))+
geom_point(aes(color = factor(gear), shape = factor(gear)))+
geom_line(aes(color = factor(gear)))

p
```

This code produces following plot:
[image]

Now, if I use

```
ggplotly(p)
```

I get the following plot where it shows two sets of legend. Is there any way to make Plotly legend behave as ggplot's does?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might still be an issue with ggplot2 / plotly. Alternatively, you could try:

```
plot_ly(data = mtcars,
        x= ~mpg, y = ~wt, color = ~factor(gear),
        type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers',
        symbol = ~factor(gear),
        symbols = c('circle','triangle-up','square'))
```